# I am unable to generate a schema types using codegen

Tags: next.js, graphql, backend, schema, graphql-codegen

I get an error like this when I create a my codegen.yml file. And I tried using codegen.json instead but the command

```
"npx graphql-codegen"
```

does not generates the code. However I have added the

```
"generates":graphql-codegen"
```

in my scripts in the package.json file.

Below is the error I keep getting.

[image: Error in my codegen.yml]

I have tried to update the graphql-codegen but that did not work.
I have also installed it globally